# make a JComponent opaque

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I'm trying to make a `JComponent` opaque in the right border.

I want make a object with my specific characteristics so i'm using a `JComponent` that can be opaque

this is because I will make a library, and I don't want to use `JPanel` or `JLabel`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProbadorCodigos {

    JFrame Frame=new JFrame();
    JComponent BORDEDE=new JComponent() {private static final long serialVersionUID = 2222L;};

    public ProbadorCodigos() {

        Frame.setSize(500, 500);
        Frame.setResizable(false);
        Frame.setUndecorated(false);
        Frame.setLayout(null);
        Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        Format();
        Action();
    }


    private void Format() {

        BORDEDE.setBounds(Frame.getWidth()-100, 0, 100, Frame.getHeight());
        BORDEDE.setOpaque(true);
        BORDEDE.setVisible(true);
        BORDEDE.setEnabled(true);
        BORDEDE.setFocusable(true);
        BORDEDE.setBackground(Color.red);
        System.out.println(BORDEDE);
    }
    private void Action() {


        Frame.add(BORDEDE);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ProbadorCodigos Ventana=new ProbadorCodigos();
        Ventana.Frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image: noo]

I don't know why it don't shows opaque, if I use a `JLabel` works so what I missing?

thanks for your advices and answers

Comment: `"and it's not a good idea use a lot of imports so I don't want to use JPanel or JLabel"` -- huh? Please explain this because it really doesn't make sense? Also, how is your component misbehaving. How do you demonstrate that it is not opaque?

Comment: mmm I don't want to use JPanel or JLabel because they have unecesary methods that i dont need

Comment: That doesn't explain your motivation for not wanting to use a JPanel, which is opaque by its nature. Also, please address my other questions in my comment above. How do you know that your JComponent is in fact not opaque? Are you filling it with an image or a background color in its `paintComponent(...)` method?

Comment: Note that while your JComponent may be opaque, calling `setBackground(...)` might not be enough (as it would be for a JPanel). I think that you need to call `g.fillRect(...)` or perhaps even better `clearRect(...)` (if you did set a background color) on it in its `paintComponent(...)` method, since it doesn't do this by default with `setBackground(...)`. Otherwise, for simpler code, simply use a JPanel. It really doesn't have many more methods than a JComponent, and I can't imagine any significant cost to your application with its use, despite having to import another class (issue w/ that?).

Comment: No mm the code above it's all what i got... i'm not very good at english sorry if can explain well, I want to make my own JComponet i don't want to use others like JPanel or JLabel, the problem is that the method SetOpaque doesn't work and I don't know why

Comment: Again, what I'm trying to say is that setOpaque works **fine**, although your understanding of what it means may not be correct. I'm trying to elucidate just what you think it means, and again, why you wouldn't simply use a JPanel. You've still refused to offer any reasonable justification for not using this.

Comment: I want to make my own JComponet i don't want to use others like JPanel or JLabel, these extends a JComponent, I'm going to put a image to demostrate that for some reazon it doesn't work

Comment: But a JPanel ***is*** a JComponent, and thus has all the properties of a JComponent with **the additional property of filling its background**, the property you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion for general ease of solving your problem: use a JPanel. Until you show good reason for not using this as the basis for your class, it remains in my mind the best solution for your problem. Otherwise, you'll need some code like:

```
JComponent bordede = new JComponent() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2222L;

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     int width = getWidth();
     int height = getHeight();
     g.setColor(getBackground());
     g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  }
};
```

Which again is not necessary if you simply used a JPanel.

Other problems with your code:

- Your code does not comply with Java naming conventions and so will confuse other Java programmers.
- You are using a null layout and `setBounds(...)` which will result in the creation of a rigid hard to enhance and debug GUI. You should avoid using this type of layout.

Comment: yes its works now.. but I think that my reazon is good "I want to make my own JComponet I don't want to use others like `JPanel` or `JLabel`, these extends a JComponent"